# Google chart displays information

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I work with API of Google Chart Tools and I would like to add more information in my tooltip. 
I have this chart:

[image]

Now, tooltip shows Febrero, Tweets: 184 but I would like to show on tooltip, v.gr. {Febero, Tweets: 184, Inicio campaña}

My code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Mes');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Tweets');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Replies');
        data.addRows(4);
        data.setValue(0, 0, 'Diciembre');
        data.setValue(0, 1, 155);
        data.setValue(0, 2, 25);
        data.setValue(1, 0, 'Enero');
        data.setValue(1, 1, 146);
        data.setValue(1, 2, 15);
        data.setValue(2, 0, 'Febrero');
        data.setValue(2, 1, 184);
        data.setValue(2, 2, 35);
        data.setValue(3, 0, 'Marzo');
        data.setValue(3, 1, 188);
        data.setValue(3, 2, 43);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                  width: 500, height: 400,
                  vAxis: {maxValue: 10}}
          );
}
​
```